# How can we make City State and Country Dropdown in dspace?

Tags: dspace

How we create three `DropDownList` to display countries, states and cities. When we select a country then its automatically shows the states name of that country in next `DropDownList`. Then when we select a state, the cities `DropDownList` will fetch the related cities for that state.
A drop down list is created [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Alter+submission+input+forms).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to create your own custom controlled vocabulary and use the DSpace [controlled vocabulary lookup mechanism](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Authority+Control+of+Metadata+Values#AuthorityControlofMetadataValues-Howtoinvokeacontrolledvocabularyfrominput-forms.xml).

If you don't wish to go the controlled vocabulary route, I see two options:

1. Define the field as one of the standard input form types in input-forms.xml but inject JavaScript into the submission process that transforms it into your series of drop-down boxes. Other than injecting the JavaScript (how to do this differs between XMLUI vs JSPUI and also between XMLUI themes), this change would need no code customisations.
2. Extend the set of input form types available to include one that meets your needs. This requires code customisations. You would probably also have to inject some JavaScript code that enables the dynamic behaviour you describe (narrow down state by country etc).

Comment: Thanks fo ryour answer. Can you just explain what type of customization it requires.